# The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>" in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have a pyspark task on zeppelin which is reading some parquet files and do some `reduce` and `filter` on it. I've gotten the follwoing error in the middle of the task in zeppelin (when applying the `reduce`):

```
from operator import add
result = data_rdd.filter(lambda log: log['test'] == "test" and (log['index'] is not None))
.map(lambda log: (int(log['index']),1)).reduceByKey(add).collect()
```

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4235 in stage 66.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4235.3 in stage 66.0 (TID 9583, , executor 2): com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to unmarshall error response (The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".). Response Code: 502, Response Text: Bad Gateway

Although I didn't get the error again, my question is anybody knows what happened here?

I should notice that the Ceph is not down in that time!

Comment: `log['index'] is not None`... but we don't really know about `log['index_2']` or do we? Also what is `add`?

Comment: It seems your message has been truncated when sent. Did you change any config to fix the problem?

Comment: @Attersson it is not the matter, as I know it is not null! But change it to be clear. Also, add the header for the `add` keyword.

Comment: @AfshinAmiri yes. it's part of the message, but the other parts are not infromative.